# AWS Lambda, Scaling, Implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, scalability

I'm looking for a specific piece of documentation about the scaling of AWS Lambda.

How I think the scaling works:

Scenario: high traffic
AWS spins up multiple instances of the same Lambda Function
AWS distributes the events (probably evenly) among the instances

So what am I looking for specifically?
Is there a document where AWS states how lambda works internally or any information that concerns the process I described above (I need something to quote).

Thank you.

Comment: The only documents I have seen are this blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-aws-lambda-function-concurrency/
and this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html These are not exactly what you are looking for i guess.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, none of the implementation details of how AWS Lambda operates should impact your usage of the service. All you need to know is that something triggers a Lambda function, it runs and exits.

There is a **limit on the number of simultaneous functions** that can run (but you can ask for an increase in this limit). There is no guarantee that the functions run in a specific order.

The reality, however, is that Lambda functions are deployed as containers and those **containers *might* be reused**. For example, if you have a function that runs once per second for 200ms, it is quite likely that the container will be reused. The benefit of this is that there is no initialization time for the container if it is reused. This is particularly beneficial for Java functions that require creation of a JVM.

It also means that your function should assume that the environment will be reused — it should cleanup temporary files and reset global variables.

For more details, see: [Understanding Container Reuse in AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/)

Comment: I know that much, but I was looking for a quote specifically. I'm writing a thesis about cloud-computing and I have a chapter about FaaS. I explain the general concept behind AWS Lambda. And there I would like to have a solid proof that this is really what's going on behind the scenes.